# BigQuery UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table — 96, but I use "insert ... select", it still does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

```
Data Manipulation Language statements
The following limits apply to Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements.

Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table — 96
Maximum INSERT statements per day per table — 1,000
```

So update and delete has very small limits, and Insert has relatively high limit. So I am trying to use "INSERT ... SELECT ..." statements instead of UPDATE.

In simple words, any records in TABLE1 I want to update, I select them and insert them into another table, TABLE2. Also I need to make sure that these records are not in TABLE2 already.

```
INSERT TABLE2 (...)
SELECT ....
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (RECORDS NOT IN TABLE2 YET)
```

It seems a good idea. But sadly I found out the above statement, even I did not use UPDATE and DELETE.

I can only run the above statement 48 times.

I don't know where this 48 times limits coming from.

It seems that BigQuery thinks that the following statement counted 2 update/delete.

```
INSERT TABLE2 (...)
SELECT ....
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (RECORDS NOT IN TABLE2 YET)
```

Any advices?

Comment: pseudo code is not always representing real code you use - can  you show the real code!

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, I posted the codes below. Only remove a few fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($ranks as rank) {
        $query = "INSERT `{$dailyReport}`

        (id, userId, artistId, release_id, track_id)

        SELECT id, userId, artistId, release_id, track_id
            FROM `{$processedDailyReport}` 

        WHERE 

        rank = @rank

        AND selected = 1

        AND id NOT IN (
          SELECT
            id
          FROM
            `{$dailyReport}`)
        ";

        $job = $this->bigQuery->runQuery($query, ['parameters' => ['useLegacySql' => false, 'rank' => $rank]]);

        $response = $this->isCloudJobSuccessful($job, 'Select report successfully ');

        if ($response['status'] === true) {

                sleep(3); //every 2 second one call limit

            } else {
                $error = $response['message'];
                $error .= $job->id(). " " .$job->info();
                return $this->returnResponse(null, 400, $error);
            }

}
```

I made the changes. I sleep 3 seconds before issue the next insert statement to the same table.

This seems solve the problem.

So the update limit quota I hit before is "Maximum rate of table metadata update operations — 1 operation every 2 seconds per table" not the 'Maximum INSERT statements per day per table — 1,000"

---

Maximum rate of table metadata update operations — 1 operation every 2 seconds per table
The table metadata update limit includes all metadata update operations performed using the BigQuery web UI, the bq command-line tool, or by calling the tables.insert, tables.patch, or tables.update API methods. This limit also applies to jobs output.

---

My guess, when I run the old statement (without sleep). It just warmed up the bigquery, and a few runs later, BigQuery performed faster, and it hits the limit "1 operation every 2 seconds per table".

---

Confirmed by Google Cloud support team:

"location": "table.write"  in the job error is about "1 operation every 2 seconds per table" limit.

The error message I got is

```
{                                                                                                                 
"error": {                                                                                                       
"errors": [                                                                                                     
 {                                                                                                              
  "domain": "global",                                                                                           
  "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",                                                                                
  "message": "Exceeded rate limits: Your table exceeded quota for table 
 update operations. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",                                                 
  "locationType": "other",                                                                                      
  "location": "table.write"                                                                                     
 }                                                                                                              
],                                                                                                              
"code": 403,                                                                                                    
"message": "Exceeded rate limits: Your table exceeded quota for table update operations. For more information,  
see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"                                                    
 }                                                                                                              
}
```

So Yes. The limit I hit is "1 operation every 2 seconds per table"